# Как поместить arguments в call

Tags: javascript

Я хочу запускать функцию не теряя контекст, но при этом имея возможность не привязываться к количеству аргументов

```js
var a = (function() {
    this.a = 1;
    this.b = function(a, b) {
      alert(a + b + this.a);
    };
  })(),

  b = function() {
    this.a = 2;
    this.c = function() {
      return a.b.call(a, arguments);
    };
  };

(new b()).c('2', '3');
```

выдает ошибку

```
VM254:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'b' of undefined
    at b.c (<anonymous>:7:36)
    at <anonymous>:9:11
```

потому что '3' ушло в первый аргумент как если бы мы вызвали a.b(['2','3']);

Comment: Использовать `apply`

Comment: @AlexeyTen такая же ошибка

Comment: ошибка не из-за этого, а из-за неправильной инициализации переменной `a` - она у тебя `undefined` - поэтому все и падает

Comment: @Grundy спасибо -> круто!